# How do I curve an edge? Bevel not working!

Tags: edges, bevel, fcurves

[image]can someone help me with curving an edge? I have a giant spiral and want to make it round instead of being made up of straight lines. Bevel does nothing so guessing there must be a way of selecting everything and making the edges rounded. I've added a pic with the yellow line showing how I want the curve to look like and red line how it is now

Cheers, Dan

Comment: Try adding a Subdivision Surface Modifier. Also, right click (in object mode) and select "shade smooth".

Comment: Thanks Chris although it didn't work unfortunately. Also I forgot to say that I want to curve every line in the spiral not just the outside so wondering if that's possible? From a distance it's fine although I'll be zooming down onto it in the final video so the lines need to be curved..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *LoopTools > Curve* tool: Enable the *LoopTools* addon (available by default in Blender), select 3 vertices of the edge, right click > *LoopTools > Curve*. Play with the parameters in the *Operator* box if needed.

[image]

Comment: sadly that hasn't worked either. I thought that considering every shape is blender is made from straight lines that there must be a simple way of selecting every straight edge in say a 20 sided circle and making it smooth/round..

Comment: what do you mean when you say that it didn't work? what was the result? there's no reason it can't work

Comment: Hi Moonboots, sorry, my brain is fully blended so prob not explaining very well.. I meant that it extruded random sections of the mesh to random places.I managed to do it now by subdividing and adjusting the 'smooth' slider to 1.000

Comment: @DanAbel  It may not be working because the your boundary is not a quad-sided loop. (2 faces at each vert) Merge enough verts to have a topo near the edge like moonboots'.. should be OK

Comment: ok thanks will look at that too as I'll be extruding the edges next